# Issue with character data type length in R & decimal precision

Tags: r, type-conversion

Trying to create a function to get the precision of numeric data. (the number of digits to the right of the decimal place)

```
    decimalplaces <- function(x) {
            if (x %% 1 != 0) {
                    pattern <- "^([0-9]+)[.]([0-9]+)$"
                    dec_part <- gsub(pattern,"\\2", x)            
                    nchar(dec_part)
            } else { 
                    return(0) 
        }
    }
```

The issue occurs with values with more than 16 digits -- `nchar` coerces "dec_part" to a string which can only store 16 digits.

Is there a way to overcome this limitation in R?

Are there alternatives to `nchar` for numeric data?

(R version 3.1.1 64 bit)

Answer (score 2):

The 'problem' is not in `nchar` but in `gsub`, which applies `as.character` to a non-character `x`. The documentation for `as.character` says:

> as.character represents real and complex numbers to 15 significant
>   digits (technically the compiler's setting of the ISO C constant
>   DBL_DIG, which will be 15 on machines supporting IEC60559 arithmetic
>   according to the C99 standard). This ensures that all the digits in
>   the result will be reliable (and not the result of representation
>   error), but does mean that conversion to character and back to numeric
>   may change the number. If you want to convert numbers to character
>   with the maximum possible precision, use format.

So, you can use

```
dec_part <- gsub(pattern,"\\2", format(x,digits=22))
```

instead of

```
dec_part <- gsub(pattern,"\\2", x)
```

in your code, but be careful because the 15 significant digit limit was set for a good reason, so there is a good chance to find just noise in trailing numbers. For example,

```
> format(1/3,digits=22)
[1] "0.3333333333333333148296"
```